# jdk version 8 silent install doesn't update path environment variable

Tags: java, path, installation, silent

I am installing JDK 8 171 on windows 2016 server core using Ansible.  When I install using the GUI, it updates my path on my workstation.  But when I do it silently it does not.  I will have to make Ansible update the path or the batch files if it won't, but that means changing the code for every new version of Java.  I wanted to use JRE, but that fails to install at all on core 2016 with Ansible, it tries to update JavaWS reg settings for browsers and as there are no browsers, fails and rolls back.  I've extracted the MSI and run a jdkxxxx.msi /? and see no parameters to tell it to update the path.  Just wondered if anyone else had run into this, been trying different combinations for two days now and pretty much hit a wall with this now.